# Lambda Calculus reduction

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, reduction

All,

Below is the lambda expression which I am finding difficult to reduce i.e. I am not able to understand how to go about this problem.

```
(λm λn λa λb . m (n a b) b) (λ f x. x) (λ f x. f x)
```

This is what I tried, but I am stuck:

Considering the above expression as : `(λm. E) M` equates to

```
E = (λn λa λb. m (n a b) b)  
M = (λf x. x) (λ f x. f x)  

 => (λn λa λb. (λ f x. x) (λ f x. f x) (n a b) b)
```

Considering the above expression as `(λn. E) M` equates to

```
E = (λa λb. (λ f x. x) (λ f x. f x) (n a b) b)  
M = ??
```

.. and I am lost!!

Can anyone please help me understand that, for ANY lambda calculus expression, what should be the steps to perform reduction?

Comment: I think you have the right idea.  One question - do lambdas associate from left to right or right to left?  In your example, for instance, you are associating them from right to left.

Comment: Also - what is (λ f x. x)?  Is that some kind of shorthand for (λ f. λx. x)?

Comment: @danben: Function application is left associative and abstraction is right associative. The above is abstraction if I am correct? ! And yes that is a shorthand.

Comment: @danben: Does Lambda calculus not come under Functional programming?

Comment: @darkie15 - no, this is like tagging a question about big O analysis with 'C++'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can follow the following steps to reduce lambda expressions:

1. Fully parenthesize the expression to avoid mistakes and make it more obvious where function application takes place.
2. Find a function application, i.e. find an occurrence of the pattern `(λX. e1) e2` where `X` can be any valid identifier and `e1` and `e2` can be any valid expressions.
3. Apply the function by replacing `(λx. e1) e2` with `e1'` where `e1'` is the result of replacing each free occurrence of `x` in `e1` with `e2`.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until the pattern no longer occurs. Note that this can lead to an infinite loop for non-normalizing expressions, so you should stop after 1000 iterations or so ;-)

So for your example we start with the expression

```
((λm. (λn. (λa. (λb. (m ((n a) b)) b)))) (λf. (λx. x))) (λf. (λx. (f x)))
```

Here the subexpression `(λm. (λn. (λa. (λb. (m ((n a) b)) b)))) (λf. (λx. x))` fits our pattern with `X = m`, `e1 = (λn. (λa. (λb. (m ((n a) b)) b))))` and `e2 = (λf. (λx. x))`. So after substitution we get `(λn. (λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) ((n a) b)) b)))`, which makes our whole expression:

```
(λn. (λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) ((n a) b)) b))) (λf. (λx. (f x)))
```

Now we can apply the pattern to the whole expression with `X = n`, `e1 = (λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) ((n a) b)) b))` and `e2 = (λf. (λx. (f x)))`. So after substituting we get:

```
(λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) (((λf. (λx. (f x))) a) b)) b))
```

Now `((λf. (λx. (f x))) a)` fits our pattern and becomes `(λx. (a x))`, which leads to:

```
(λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) ((λx. (a x)) b)) b))
```

This time we can apply the pattern to `((λx. (a x)) b)`, which reduces to `(a b)`, leading to:

```
(λa. (λb. ((λf. (λx. x)) (a b)) b))
```

Now apply the pattern to `((λf. (λx. x)) (a b))`, which reduces to `(λx. x)` and get:

```
(λa. (λb. b))
```

Now we're done.

Comment: sepp2k: I have a question, should the reduction be done from left to right or the other way round? Or does it not matter?

Comment: You can't get different answers by reducing in a different order.  However, doing it one way might keep reducing forever.  To avoid this you can use "normal-order reduction" which reduces the left most first.  (Or, more precisely left most and outer most - basically the one that starts the furthest to the left.) This is guaranteed to give an answer if one exists.

Comment: Thanks RD1 .. That helps. Also, I am working on the reduction ISZERO 2 where ISZERO = `λn. n (λx. FALSE) TRUE` and 2 = `λg λy. g (g y)`. I have reached the step = `( (λx. FALSE) ((λx. FALSE) TRUE) )` . Now this should return a FALSE right because there are no free `x` in the body of the outer function?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It's a function that ignores the argument x and always returns FALSE.

Answer (score 4):

Where you're going wrong is that in the first step, you can't have

```
M = (λf x. x)(λ f x. f x)
```

because the original expression doesn't include that application expression.  To make this clear, you can put in the implicit parentheses following the rule that application is left-associative (using [ and ] for the new parens and putting in some missing "."s):

```
[ (λm . λn . λa . λb . m (n a b) b) (λ f x. x) ] (λ f x. f x)
```

From here, find an expression of the form `(λv.E) M` some where inside and reduce it by replacing `v` with `M` in `E`.  Be careful that it really is an application of the function to M: it isn't if you have something like
`N (λv.E) M`, since then N is applied to the function and M as two arguments.

If you're still stuck, try putting in the parens for each lambda also - basically a new "(" after each ".", and a matching ")" that goes as far to the right as possible while still matching the new "(".  As an example, I've done one here (using [ and ] to make them stand out):

```
( (λm . λn . λa . [λb . m (n a b) b]) (λ f x. x) ) (λ f x. f x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute a thing for its corresponding thing:

```
(λm λn λa λb . m          (n            a b) b) (λ f x. x) (λ f x. f x)
= ~            ^________                        ~~~~~~~~~~
   (λn λa λb . (λ f x. x) (n            a b) b)            (λ f x. f x)
=    ~                     ^__________                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      (λa λb . (λ f x. x) ((λ f x. f x) a b) b)
=                 ~       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      (λa λb .   (λ x. x)                    b)
=                   ~  ^                     ~
      (λa λb .         b                      )
```

That is all.