# Lambda Normal Ordering

Tags: lambda-calculus

So following this previous post: 
[Lambda Calculus Reduction steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140819/lambda-calculus-reduction-steps)

I'm still confused on some parts.

If I have something like

> λx.(λz.zz)(λy.y)x

Notation from linked post:

> (λ param . output)input

The Param would be **λx**, but would the output be **(λz.zz)** with **(λy.y)** being the input? Or would the input be **(λz.zz)(λy.y)** and **x** is the input?

-
I want to say its

> (λx.(λz.zz))(λy.y)) x

with the output being (λz.zz) with (λy.y) being the input since that one CAN be the first one to be worked on.

My steps, not sure if it is correct:

> 1. (λx.(λz.zz))(λy.y)) x
>
> (λy.y) gets dropped because there is no x to replace
>
> 2. (λz.zz)x
> 3. xx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding parentheses to your initial expression makes it:
`λx.(((λz.zz) (λy.y)) x)`
Here, there is only one reduction you can do:
`((λz.zz) (λy.y)) => ((λy.y) (λy.y)) => λy.y` 
So the original expression becomes 
`λx.((λy.y) x)`
which reduces to
`λx.x`
which is a normal form.