# Lambda reduction

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, reduction

I'm having trouble understanding how to reduce lambda terms to normal form. could someone help me to understand how to reduce this lambda expression? I don't know exactly where to start.

**(λx. ( λa. (λx. x a)) x) 20 (λx. x+3)**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'll just focus on your expression. For a deeper explanation, you could read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140819/lambda-calculus-reduction-steps).

First of all, let's consider how brackets could be interpreted on these expressions. Consider the following expression:

```
(λx. x*x) 5 => 5*5 => 25
```

So, evaluation of this expression is done replacing the *x* by value *5* outside brackets.

Now, let's put some brackets from left to right on your expression:

```
(((λx. ( λa. (λx. x a)) x) 20) (λx. x+3))
```

Let's call *(λa. (λx. x a))* the variable *z* as a simplification. So, we'll have:

```
(((λx. z x) 20) (λx. x+3))
```

and the expression is now similar to our first example. Replacing *x* by value *20*, we'll have:

```
((z 20) (λx. x+3))
```

which is the same as:

```
(((λa. (λx. x a)) 20) (λx. x+3))
```

Again, we can replace *a* by *20* resulting

```
((λx. x 20) (λx. x+3))
```

Afterwards, we could replace *x* at the left expression by the whole expression on the right (λx. x+3).

```
((λx. x+3) 20)
```

Finally, we could replace *x* by *20*:

```
((λx. x+3) 20) => 20+3 = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Proceed by substitution, left-to-right:

```
(λx.      ( λa. (λx. x a )) x )  20  (λx. x+3)
~~
([x:= 20] ( λa. (λx. x a )) x )      (λx. x+3)
~~
          ( λa. (λx. x a )) 20       (λx. x+3)
~~
      ( [a:=20] (λx. x a ))          (λx. x+3)
~~
                (λx. x 20)           (λx. x+3)
~~
     ([x:=(λx. x+3)] x 20)
~~
          (λx. x+3)    20
~~
      ([x:=20] x+3)
~~
              20+3
```

There's no more reductions to perform, thus this is the normal form of the original lambda term.