# beta-reduction in lambda-calculus

Tags: ocaml, lambda-calculus

I am extremely confused about this one.

- Given the following rule ("Type and Programming Languages", Benjamin Pierce, page 72):

```
(λx.t)v2 -> [x -> v2]t (* E-AppAbs*)
```

Later in the same book, at page 87, we have (I simplified):

```ml
let is_value (e : expr) =
  match e with
  | Abstr (_, _)->true
  | _ -> false

let rec step e =
  match e with
  | App(Abstr(x, t1), v2) when is_value v2 -> subst x v2 t1 (*E-AppAbs*)
  | App(e1, e2) when is_value e1 -> App (e1, step e2) (*E-App2*)
  | App(e1, e2) -> App(step e1, e2) (*E-App1*)
  | _ -> raise NoRuleApplies
```

Note that `is_value v2` is a necessary precondition before calling `subst`.
I hence, conclude that the term `(λx.x)y`
Is **not reducible**, because *y* is not a an abstraction.

- **However**, I keep seeing this:
  [image]

(this is a screenshot from a [Chicago university pdf](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2002/winter/CS33600/slides/Lesson2.pdf), page 4)

Similarly, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140819/lambda-calculus-reduction-steps), we can see that the accepted answers does:

```
(λx.xy)z   ->*   zy
```

This comes as contradiction to me, because, again, `z` above is not an abstraction.

**Question**: I don't understand what I am missing in definition, and why everyone keeps reducing stuff?

Comment: `(λx.x)y` would reduce in one "step"  to `(λx.x) (step y)`, the evaluation of which will raise an exception.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, that's how I see it. However, that doesn't seem to be the case for examples I encounter on internet & in the book

Comment: I guess I would conclude that Pierce is using different definitions at this point from these other examples. FWIW I tried Pierce's code and indeed it doesn't seem to reduce either of the two examples you give. (The exception just causes evaluation to stop, it's not an error per se.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow and belongs instead on https://cs.stackexchange.com/. SO is for practical programming problems, not theoretical questions. See [help/on-topic]. (OCaml happens to have a high degree of academics in its programming community, so it isn't unlikely that you will receive a good answer here, but I still think you're much more likely to get a good answer on CS)

Comment: it seems you need to add a clause to `is_value` to also admit naked variables as values, to make it work. something like `match e with
  | Abstr (_, _)->true | App(_,_) -> false
  | _ -> true`